# "Cannot end a section without first starting one" - Laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, ssl-certificate

Since I had an SSL certificate installed on my shared server, I have the following error:

> Cannot end a section without first starting one

Additionally, this error only appears on pages that use the database. Static pages have no errors.

Everything worked very well before and everything works very well locally too.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.32.

Any ideas ?

*I have not inserted my code here because it is the same code in static pages as in dynamic pages. (Except for the content of sections) ... If you think you need it to solve my problem, just ask, please! Personally, I do not think it's a code problem as much as a compatibility issue. But maybe I'm wrong...*

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Here some code (after comments...):

**My blade:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('meta')
   <meta property="og:title" content="{!! html_entity_decode(__('Title')) !!}" />
@endsection

@section('canonical')
   <link rel="canonical" href="https://myWebSite.com" />
@endsection
```

**My layout:**

```
...
@yield('meta')
@yield('canonical')
...
```

Comment: it looks like blade template issue.you missed @section may be or extend .check your blade template

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? And which commands are you using to start/stop the sections?

Comment: Try counting the number of `@section` lines, and then the number of `@stop` + `@endsection`. Basically, you cannot use both `@stop` and `@endsection` together.

Comment: I'm am using version 5.4.32. I'm using @endsection to stop my sections. All my code (@section and @endsection) is the same in my static pages and in my dynamic pages. I have done counting several times and I do not see any problem.)

Comment: I put some code in my question...

Comment: I'm sure it is not the best thing to do, but the solution I found is to remove all @endsection except the last one. All work properly now, but... If you have another solution... please write it! :D